# How to Fix Error: URL KEY Already Exists in magento2 Import in following case

Tags: php, magento, import, magento2

We Are Using Magento2 for Our Store. We have Lot of SKU,s in the following Format.

As Magento Works, Magento2 creates URL Key from SKU.

So In this Case From First SKU URL Key should be  **sfp-10g-aOc1-5m-ao**

But In other Case From 2nd, SKU URL key also  **sfp-10g-aOc1-5m-ao**

and the same in the third case.

Please tell me how to make different URL keys in case of Magento import.

```
1. SFP-10G-AOC1.5M-AO
2. SFP-10G-AOC1-5M-AO 
3. SFP-10G-AOC1/5M-AO
```

Comment: Try the extension mentioned under https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213036/url-was-already-generated-for-an-item-with-sku-error maybe.

Comment: you can add number sequence as well with your SKU to avoid this error

Comment: Please give me modification required in magento2 import